# Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL in facebook

Tags: javascript, c#, html

[image: facebook error]

```
<li class="active">
  <a id="shareFB" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL&t=TITLE"
  onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">Facebook</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("shareFB").setAttribute("href", "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + document.URL);</script>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi @Kapil-Nayan, please provide wich error you faced.

Comment: Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL

Comment: Can you post the concatenated string which is interpreted as 'invalid' in this case? or even if you can post the pattern of the URL...of how it is currently and how you expect it to be?

Comment: URL: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FUBRealityWeb%2FHome%2Ftest&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=like&kid_directed_site=0&app_id=607214719787733

Comment: @ShivamDhagat is this the 'invalid' one or the expected one? asking this because when I clicked on it, it gave me the facebook login page.

Comment: it is Invalid one and yes it will redirect you to your FB page first to log in....

Comment: @ShivamDhagat in your url, you have '?u=http...' . can you try by replacing 'u' with 'href' in the url

Answer (score 27):

Are your using localHost. ? if you are using some plugins for share and you are in localHost then that's the issue. It will work fine when u deploy

Answer (score 7):

In your url, you have 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=...' . You should try replacing 'u' with 'href' in this url.

Comment: if you use `href` it'll be 2-step process when sharing instead of one. `u` works fine as long as it's not localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this at your local development environment?

I'm getting this error on localhost but it works OK when a normal URL is supplied. Here's a dummy implementation. This works on my application during development:

```
const share = 'https://test-location.com';
const appId = 'your app id here';

<a
href=`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=${appId}&sdk=joey&u=${share}&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button"
target="_blank"
>
Share
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```js
 function sethref() 
 {
  document.getElementById("shareFB").setAttribute("href","https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL));
 }
 
window.onload = sethref;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <title>Web Page Design</title>
   <body>
     <a id="shareFB">FB</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried it but same Error Url Generated is :: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FUBRealityWeb%2FHome%2FTest

Comment: I am trying it in LocalHost, is it not the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should escape or encode the URL that you are passing

```
document.getElementById("shareFB").setAttribute("href", "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL));
```

Comment: I have tried it but it does nt help same issue  :Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL